# Azure Portal: How to restrict IP address access to app deployed in an Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, neo4j, azureportal

I have a Linux virtual machine provisioned in Azure. I setup Neo4j inside the virtual machine and the Neo4j browser can be accessed through

`http://vm.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:7474/browser/`

How to I restrict access to this url to certain ip addresses only? How to do this in the new Azure Portal?

Comment: You already are protecting with password right?

Comment: @ManuelHernandez Yes, but it only needs to be accessed by developers since this is in staging. and for some other specific reason :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to look at Network Security Groups. Here's the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal

Same way you can restrict IP Addresses to access certain ports. The final action would be deny, instead of allow. And, obviously, you would need to specify a CIDR range.

Comment: I'm looking for something where I can input the actual ip address that can access the url. I've already added inbound rules to my network security group to allow access to Neo4j, SSH and FTP. But not from specific IP addresses

Comment: you can do that with NSG, you need to select `CIDR Block` as `Source` (instead of `Any`) and specify allowed IP's or disallowed IP's.